# Setting Tol for XGBoost Early Stopping

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am using XGBoost with early stopping. After about 1000 epochs, the model is still improving, but the magnitude of improvement is very low. I.e.:

```
 clf = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=num_rounds, evals=watchlist, early_stopping_rounds=10)
```

Is it possible to set a "tol" for early stopping? I.e.: the minimum level of improvement that is required to not trigger early stopping.

Tol is a common parameter in SKLearn models, such as MLPClassifier and QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that there is a parameter `tol` in xgboost but you can set the `early_stopping_round` higher. This parameters means that if the performance on the test set does not improve for `early_stopping_round` times, then it stops. If you know that after 1000 epochs your model is still improving but very slowly, set `early_stopping_round` at 50 for example so it will be more "tolerante" about small changes in performance.

Comment: Did you mean to say setting the `early_stopping_round` lower (instead of higher)? A low values would terminate earlier than a high value.

Answer (score 1):

The [issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4982) is still open in XGBoost Github's repo, so even though the wrappers such as `sklearn` and `h2o` seem to already have this feature, `xgboost` itself is still lacking the `stopping_tolerance` hyperparameter...

Let's upvote [it here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4982#issuecomment-546240564) to speed things up a bit, shall we?

Answer (score 1):

This option [has been implemented](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/6942/commits/277674ab4ff4f86d462a923a35d2ad2a91ad6e92).

Simply pass a value to `tolerance`:

```
    early_stop = xgb.callback.EarlyStopping(tolerance=1e5)

    booster = xgb.train(
        {'objective': 'binary:logistic',
         'eval_metric': ['error', 'rmse']},
        D_train,
        evals=[(D_train, 'Train'), (D_valid, 'Valid')],
        callbacks=[early_stop],
        )
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I worked with xgboost.XGBRegressor(), and did not figure out how to set the tolerance after studying all the answers in this post. 

My xgbregressor did not stop even the rmse grows very slowly like below.  

[585] validation_1-rmse:55221.87637
[586] validation_1-rmse:55221.58118
[587] validation_1-rmse:55220.68734

Can you please show me a sample code, for example, I want to only compare the integer part of RMSE ?

Comment: I use import xgboost as xgb    xgb.XGBRegressor()

Comment: Im not sure if I understand. Your RMSE between step 585 and 586 has a difference of 0.2952 > 1e5.. the algorithm is not meant to early stop at this point yet..

Comment: Thanks for your reply . For my data, 0.2925 difference is insignificant. I would like to round up RMSE to integer. So my tree can stop early. How can I do it ?

Comment: well you just change the parameter tolerance to the minimal integer difference you would like, say `tolerance=1`

Comment: I am new to python and ML, so sorry to bother you with ruby questions.  my callback did not work.   import xgboost as xgb (version=1.7.3)    early_stop=xgb.callback.EarlyStopping(tolerance=1e5)    error: _init_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tolerance'      what did I miss?  really appreciate it.

Comment: If I [look here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/7137), the parameter name was changed to `min_delta`, please read for yourself and report back how you went