# R XGBoost early stopping by

Tags: r, xgboost, early-stopping

Below I have code, in which I am trying to train an XGBoost model in R that early stops after a given number of rounds `early_stopping_rounds` without improvement.

```
watchlist <- list(train=dtrain, test=dtest)

param <- list(
  objective = "binary:logistic",
  eta = 0.3,
  max_depth = 8,
  eval_metric="logloss"
)

xgb.train(params = param, data = dtrain, nrounds = 1000, watchlist = watchlist, early_stopping_rounds = 3)
```

However, instead of fixing the number of rounds, I would like to pass a `min_delta` value, so the early stopping kicks in when the difference between rounds is below a given tolerance.

Others ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772623/setting-tol-for-xgboost-early-stopping) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969675/will-xgboost-early-stopping-stop-after-marginal-improvements)) have asked this for Python.
However, [advances not too long ago have implemented this option for Python](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/6942/commits/277674ab4ff4f86d462a923a35d2ad2a91ad6e92).

But how do I work this out in R? Is there something like it?